# Strange scala 3 syntax - new without type

Tags: scala, scala-3

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => IO[B]): IO[B] = new:
  def unsafeRun = f(self.unsafeRun).unsafeRun
```

This method creates a new IO object

I don't understand the use of new without a type. Feels like structural type, but not quite sure. I'm Just starting to transition to scala 3.

Comment: This syntax existed in Scala 2 too, with braces instead. `new { def unsafeRun = ??? }`.

Comment: what construct of the language is it ? is it a structural type ?

Comment: anonymous class ?

Comment: @HTNW I am pretty sure the syntax did not exist in **Scala 2**, you needed to do `new IO { }` i.e. name the class you are instantiating. - Maat, **Scala 3** allows you to omit that type if it can be inferred, in this case from the return type. Personally, I do not know how to feel about it, I also find it confusing at first but you should be able to know which one is being inferred quite easily. - PS: Yes, this is just creating an anonymous class.

Comment: It's an anonymous class with inferred type. It's one of "cursed" features described on this presentation https://www.youtube.com/live/JRgq8jjE2Dk?si=paeHfA8uLAOBmwlD&t=3104.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The syntax exists in Scala 2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/0MlgchofTNCq7YQVadZjNg/5 `new { def unsafeRun = ??? }` is a shorthand for `new AnyRef { def unsafeRun = ??? }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Oh, maybe you meant not the syntax but the feature with type inference from the left hand side.

Comment: @DmytroMitin while you are correct that I meant the inference part, I also thought just doing `new { ... }` would work in **Scala 2**. That is kind of cursed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you described is a new feature of Scala 3, which allows you to drop type name when creating an anonymous instance of some class if the type can be inferred:

```
trait Foo {
  def a(i: Int): String
}

// this is what Scala 2 requires
val foo1: Foo = new Foo {
  def a(i: Int): String = i.toString
}

// this is what Scala 3 allows
val foo2: Foo = new { // Foo in inferred from value foo2 type
  def a(i: Int): String = i.toString
}

// this is Scala 3 with braceless syntax
val foo3: Foo = new:
  def a(i: Int): String = i.toString
```

While it *feels* like a structural typing it's a *nominal* typing with type inference extended to anonymous classes created with `new` keyword.

You could even use this in some nested contexts like:

```
trait Foo:
  def a(i: Int): String
trait Bar:
  def foo: Foo
trait Baz:
  def bar: Bar

val baz: Baz = new:
  def bar = new:
    def foo = new:
      def a(i: Int): String = i.toString
```

but it becomes unreadable almost immediately, which is why [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/live/JRgq8jjE2Dk?si=FwW49QmmpDescOJp&t=3104) classifies it as an Scala-3-specific antipattern.

It might be a really nice way to quickly to hack some one-time-use script, but please avoid using it in larger long-living codebases.

Comment: I remember Martin being too fond of this change, and IMHO I don't understand what is the fuzz for reducing too little boilerplate that actually eases the readability.